# Errors in hadoop fs -cat command while writing output of text delimited table into local unix

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have very huge amount of data stored in a text delimited table whose `DDL` I created through `Impala`, I have written it with data in `Hive` and I want to get it to `local file system` in `Unix` in a single file.
I have multiple files in `HDFS` table location path, this is the command I used:

`hadoop fs -cat '<tablelocationinHDFS>/*' > /unixlocalpathandfilename.csv`

I'm getting 2 errors:

1. `cat: is a directory error`
   Because there is one *impala_insert_staging* directory inside it, how do I avoid this error?
2. `cat: Unable to write to output stream`

Or Should I be getting data into Local using `get` command or `getmerge` command into a single file?
How do I avoid the above errors and have a successful run of command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge [-nl] <localdst> /unixlocalpath

-nl  Add a newline character at the end of each file.
```

Comment: I would appreciate you click my solution as accepted solution. Regards